# Google Apps Script Add-On Source Code/Security

Tags: security, google-apps-script, google-apps

I'm building a Google Apps Script Add-On and wanted to know whether anyone can access the underlying source code when I publish it to the Marketplace?  I want to store a password/private key in the code and wanted to make sure no one who installs the app can access it.

Using a Google Apps Script Library allows a user to use their own script to step into the source code, so that's an example of a public library whose source code is visible to the end user.

Failing that, is there a better solution for storing a password/private key?

Thank you.

Comment: you cant see server side code which is where your passwords and such should live.

Comment: You can check this page https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties first tab explain what kind of data you can store in properties. For your case scriptproperties is the best one. The all users mention in the table are users who can access the code, users who access addon don't have access to the code.

Comment: Hi St3ph, thanks for the answer, that seems like a perfect fit for what I need.

Answer (score 2):

From the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878136/google-apps-script-add-on-source-code-security#comment53603967_32878136) by [St3ph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3556215/st3ph)

> You can check this page https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties first tab explain what kind of data you can store in properties. For your case scriptproperties is the best one. The all users mention in the table are users who can access the code, users who access addon don't have access to the code.