# Get code from my google spreadsheet addon after publishing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, add-on

I had published a private addon on google spreadsheet. However, the problem is, I lost the app script source code for my addon. I need to make some changes and publish it again.

How can I possibly get/download the code from the spreadsheet addon that I published on the chrome web-store?

I tried looking on https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard where there is a list of all my addons published but there's no option for reading the source code. A quick google search reveals nothing regarding this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

I figured out a way to find the code.

From your developer dashboard: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard

click on `more info` and then click to download the `main.crx` file for the addon you're interested in.

`main.crx` is a zip file which you should be able to unzip.  On linux or mac you can do it from the command line `unzip yourfilename_main.crx`

open up `manifest.json` and look for "container_id" the string after that is the file ID of your script.

https://script.google.com/d/**container_id_of_your_script_here**/edit

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to get the source code from the Chrome Web Store. Instead you have to find the file that holds your Google Apps Script project. Take a look to the Trash of your Google Drive. For further details see [Find or recover a file - Google Drive Help](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/1716222?hl=en)