# Share Google Sheet, but keep script private

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've created a Google Sheet version of my [android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brianpgrissom.nutritioncalculator&hl=en). I'm trying to make it more accessible and easier to deal with. I've got it working about how I want, but the back-end is written in the google api script... I'd like to keep that private. Is that possible? Is there I can let John Doe open the sheet, make their changes (to unprotected ranges) and leave? I've protected the sheets, made copies of sheets, etc. The sheet FORMULAS aren't my worry. But I haven't been able to find a way to keep the SCRIPT code private.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to protect the Apps Script code in a Google spreadsheet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075446/how-to-protect-the-apps-script-code-in-a-google-spreadsheet)