# Use a Library of Google apps script without have access in it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, shared-libraries, task-parallel-library, ios-standalone-mode

I have ID key of the master script and I have did connecting it to another users spreadsheet template as a Library but what I want to do is How to make the spreadsheet template access to the master script being limited or should be not shared.

When I'm going to deleted a master script even the library still appears on the list of clien script of the spreadsheet template but all function seperate dead completely or it has said like this:

> YOU DO NOT HAVE ACCESS TO LIBRARY *******, USED BY YOUR SCRIPT, OR IT HAS BEEN DELETED.

Comment: All users of the library must have read access. You can't link to a deleted library there must be at least one published version of the library for it to be valid.

Comment: I mean the master script still available on my google drive but my do action has just deleted user from shared of that script.  Oh.. yeah.. Spencer Easton.. I'd do understood now so conclusion is that can't be link to library without share the master script to user firstly at least readable access, right?  Oh my god if that so my script will be copied by my client with free with no-limits.  Is there any another way to get the solution to solve this problem? What about API key and also web apps from a PUBLISH menu. I've been activated both of them. How to use them and What they would work do ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try coment from @user3887038 in [Q16075446](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075446/how-to-protect-the-apps-script-code-in-a-google-spreadsheet). It make possible to hide library code, but it made difficult to updating code