# how do i see code behind the Google sheet add on?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

I created couple of google sheets add on, but then later my associated google account was disabled and can't access/edit those add ons.

Instead of starting from scratch I thought to ask here if there is a way to see the code behind the Google sheet add on?

thank you

Comment: If you are asking about a Chrome extension, then you can download the extension and view the code. The extension [Chrome extension source viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-extension-source-v/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin) may make it more convenient to do so. There are probably other extensions which will also be able to do so, or you can do it by hand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to protect the Apps Script code in a Google spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075446/how-to-protect-the-apps-script-code-in-a-google-spreadsheet)

Answer (score 1):

No such API to view source code for Add-ons, nothing mentioned in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/mobile/) atleast.