# google sheet Special formula in google script protect from copy

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a google sheet file and I created special formulas for the sheet
And I need to share the file but I want to protect my formulas from copying and viewing and that the file I shared will still work with the formulas
How can I do this?

Thank you and sorry for my English

Comment: Can you show us the code for one of your formulas here? Will be easier to show you how to edit it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to protect the Apps Script code in a Google spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075446/how-to-protect-the-apps-script-code-in-a-google-spreadsheet)

Answer (score 0):

If by special formula you mean a formula made of built-in functions on a shared spreadsheet there is no way to protect them from viewing and copying, by the other hand if you mean custom functions the only way to protect them from viewing and copying is by creating an add-on.

Comment: They will not be able to view the source code of the add on?                                                There is a possibility of remote shutting down this thing?

Comment: There is a concept but how can I create the option to disable it
I saw here
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/
in Charge users to install
That I can  "roll my own payment system or call into an existing billing database" This can help me disable the add on?
If so, you have some source to learn the subject from?

And thanks for the help

Comment: @saarsa Follow up questions should be posted as new question.

Comment: I have idea I will make a site with Google site 
and on the site I will write the emails of anyone I want to give him access to
then with XMLService and Session.getActiveUser ()
I can do a comparison of the email