# Is it possible to hide Google script from google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Rest API available which I would like to make available via an Google sheet for less tech oriented people. I was wondering if it is possible to hide the google script from the sheet if I share it with people? I have some sensitive information in the code like the authentication etc which I would like to hide. Moreover, it would be nice if they can't infer with the code. Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to protect the Apps Script code in a Google spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075446/how-to-protect-the-apps-script-code-in-a-google-spreadsheet)

Comment: There seems to be a File>share in script editor(which doesn't work now), but maybe it'll be possible in the future to change container bound access.

Answer (score 2):

The only secure way is to create an add-on.

Related

- [How to protect the Apps Script code in a Google spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16075446/1595451)