# Can we give permission to view or edit App Script in Google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've transfered project google sheet for customer. Although they have all permission to edit sheet, but i dont want them to view and edit App script that i write in it. Can we do that ?

I wanna customer can see and edit the script i write.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve but do these answer your question?: [Is it possible to hide Google script from google sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53906020/is-it-possible-to-hide-google-script-from-google-sheet), [How to protect the Apps Script code in a Google spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075446/how-to-protect-the-apps-script-code-in-a-google-spreadsheet), [Hide Apps Script code from editor of a Google Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68951097/hide-apps-script-code-from-editor-of-a-google-sheet)

Comment: If they have permission to edit a spreadsheet then they have permission to edit the script that it contains

Comment: Blocking the script from being seen is not secure for the user, and I guess Google will not move in that direction. Blocking the script from being edited can be done now using libraries.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries

May be you are interested in mark https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36763190 with a +1