# Are Google scripts attached to a readonly spreadsheet visible to the user?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working in a Google Script that runs on a a Google Spreadsheet and creates an onEdit() trigger on it.

I would like to know if this script is somehow visible (through Google's interface or any kind of source code inspection) to the users that access the table with readonly permissions.

From my understanding users would not be able to access such a script, since they are suppose to run on Google's server side and not on the client browser. I couldn't find anything about that on App Scripts documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the use of a web browser developers tools (like right click and selecting Inspect) over a spreadsheet they will not the script code if you do right clic over an spreadsheet but it might show the name of functions called by a custom menu or image with an assigned function, not the code of the `onEdit` function.

---

User with view access can't view the code but, if you didn't disable disabled make a copy, they see the code if they made a copy of the spreadsheet.

An alternative to limit users to make a copy of the spreadsheet is to publish your script as an add-on.

Related

- [How to protect the Apps Script code in a Google spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16075446/1595451)

Comment: I just edited the question considering not exclusively google's interface but also considering inspection tool usage (or any kind of source code inspection). If you have any considerations about that, It would be great to know