# Creating and testing an add-on for Google Sheets in the new Script Editor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, ide, google-workspace, add-on

I've created several internal add-ons to automate a few workflows within our company using the "old" Apps Script IDE. Now I'd like to create a new one using the all new Apps Script IDE which was released last december. All looks good and works great, however there's a few things I can't figure out.

First off: using deployments the Google Workspace Marketplace IDE states that "Your deployment ID will identify all the Google Workspace services that your app supports." when using a deploymeny ID. So, I've pasted my deployment ID in there. Just a simple script creating an add-on menu and running a function resulting in an alert:

```
function onInstall () {
  onOpen()
}

function onOpen () {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  var menu = ui.createAddonMenu()

  // Create menu structure
  menu
    .addItem('Create proposal', 'proposalShowPopup')

  // Add menu to UI
  menu.addToUi()
}

function proposalShowPopup() {
  Browser.msgBox('Test')
}
```

However, when I deploy this, I can see the listing in the marketplace, but I can't install it in the sheets where I need it.

Furthermore, probably because I haven't declared this add-on to be a Sheets add-on, I can't install the test-deployment as mentioned in this article:
[Testing Google Workspace add-ons](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/testing-gsuite-addons#new-editor) by Google. The `Install` is missing from the Apps Script's Deployments dialog.

I read a lot about the `appsscript.json` file but can't find any information on what this file should contain other than the following lines of code, applicable to my script:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Paris",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "Sheets",
        "version": "v4",
        "serviceId": "sheets"
      }
    ]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

Any ideas on how to create an Sheets only add-on using the new IDE (which works great as mentioned before)?

Any help or nudges in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you deploying the add-on? @Allard

Comment: I use the deploy button on the top right side, copy the deployment ID and use this in the Google `Workspace Marketplace IDE > App configuration` under the `Google Workspace add-on` tickbox (which states: Your deployment ID will identify all the Google Workspace services that your app supports.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The reason you cannot install the add-on in Sheets is essentially because you are not declaring in your manifest anything about the script being an add-on.**

Since you want it to be specifically used in Sheets, the manifest `appscript.json` file should look something similar to this:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Paris",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "Sheets",
        "version": "v4",
        "serviceId": "sheets"
      }
    ]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "addOns": {
    "sheets": {
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "proposalShowPopup"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that the `addOns` parameter has been added as well as with the `sheets` paramater.

The `addOns` parameter has the following structure and it represents the configuration that is used to define the add-on's content and behavior.

```
{
  "common": {
    object (Common)
  },
  "calendar": {
    object (Calendar)
  },
  "drive": {
    object (Drive)
  },
  "gmail": {
    object (Gmail)
  },
  "docs": {
    object (Docs)
  },
  "sheets": {
    object (Sheets)
  },
  "slides": {
    object (Slides)
  }
}
```

As for the `sheets` parameter it has the below structure - which is similar to the one most of the parameters from the `addOns` have; however, since you mention it as being `sheets` this will clearly indicate for which of these add-on types is meant for.

```
{
  "homepageTrigger": {
    object (HomepageTrigger)
  },
  "onFileScopeGrantedTrigger": {
    object (OnFileScopeGrantedTrigger)
  }
}
```

After setting your manifest file accordingly, you should be able to see the **Install** button pop up when going to **Test Deployments**:

[image: add on install]

#### Reference

- [Manifests for Google Workspace add-ons](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/gsuite-manifests).

Comment: Thanks much for the quick reply. Will dive into this. And thanks much for pointing me to the reference, was looking for something like this, but obviously not hard enough ;-)

Comment: You're welcome! Let me know if this ended up fixing your issue :)

Comment: This did fix my problem. Add-on is now visible in the sidebar for testing. Thanks much!

Comment: @ale13 how about Google Forms? Why there is no `forms` parameter?

Comment: @Allard if this helped you, please upvote Ale13's answer.

Comment: hi @ale13 I have been having a similar issue as the OP, whereas I *was* able to locate and click the `Install` button in the `Workspace Add On` section of the Test Deployment overlay, however, when my Add-on's custom menu item does not display as expected when I open a new/standalone google sheet. My Appsscript.json has a `addOns.sheets.homepageTrigger: { "runFunction": "onOpen"         }`  property (pls excuse the syntax-crossing) and the Appsscript.json file also has a `"oauthScopes": [ "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets" ]`. I may break this out as a new q...