# OAuth Authentication video and sign-in button for Google Sheets Editor Add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, add-on

I'm trying to publish an Google Sheets editor add-on I've made and I'm facing some roadblock.

1. Demo Video for OAuth Authentication

   For this, I'm required to create a demo video on how the user logs into the project and requesting the OAuth token with the clientid that I'm working on.

Since the add-on is not publish, does this mean I need to create a test deployment and start the OAuth process?

I found a rough guide like this
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=roxC8SMs7HU and [Creating and testing an add-on for Google Sheets in the new Script Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65905353/creating-and-testing-an-add-on-for-google-sheets-in-the-new-script-editor)
where we need to modify the appscript.json manifest.

These are the scopes I requested

[image]

2. Sign-in Branding
   from google,

> Please note, any button that launches Google OAuth must comply with the Google sign-in branding guidelines. Also, the button background can be either blue or white, but the button must always include the standard color Google "G" on a white tile. You may create a separate window pop-up that allows users to click on the Google sign-in button before the android native pop-up shows up.(Please see attached screenshots for reference.)

I do not have a mobile or web app or anything that requires a sign in button, the user should have a google account, and install the addon via the google marketplace. I don't know how should I modify the sign in button.

Hope to get some clarification.

Comment: There are two types of Apps Script add-ons, Editor and Workspace, the first might not require to manually edit the manifest. What type of add-on are trying to publish? Are you using a gmail.com or a Workspace account to publish your add-on? By the other hand, questions on this site should be specific, meaning there should be only one question / issue by post.

Comment: i selected editor addon only. im using a workspace account to publish.

Comment: The sources that you have review aren't about Editor add-ons. Regarding the video, see the answers of the linked question(s), regarding the signing branding, that is not required for Editor add-ons as is the signing process is managed by the Google Workspace Marketplace / Google Editors.