# I created a Sheet with attached Apps Script, and have shared it, but can the script source be private?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The Apps Script attached to the Sheet has a function that is meant to be called by any of the collaborators.
But the Apps Script source contains a secret key. So my collaborators should not have read access to the script, just execute access.
Is this not possible? Thank you.

Comment: Easy way is to put it in `userProperties` and give execute access through installable edit triggers+ checkbox. Other way is to publish a addon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you share a Sheet with the App Script:

- ( and you want other users to be able to edit the Sheet)
- it is not possible to keep the code hidden.

To do that you need to publish the Script as an add-on on Google Workspace Marketplace.

Please find more information on [How to publish App Script Add-on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/publish-add-on-overview)

The general question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075446/how-to-protect-the-apps-script-code-in-a-google-spreadsheet)

Comment: Thank you, may I further ask you if the problem can also be solved using stand alone Apps Script?  May I ask how to use a function in a standalone GAS from a sheet formula?

Comment: Yeah, so for a start : you cannot solve it using stadalone Apps Script, but you can try creating a library out of the Apps Script file and then using the library in a different sheet. That could work as you intended it. 2: To use a formula you need to select a range and then set the formula ( sth like : SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange( a, b).setFormula("YOUR_FORMULA")